# Include answers along with questions in SEDE query

Tags: support, data-explorer

I want to modify the query below so that the answers to the questions are also included.  The full code is [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1182670/dump-of-my-own-stackexchange-favorites).  I would also like to print/report the results in order, so question, answer1, answer2 ... Basically I'd like the results to look a lot like what one sees on the original website.  So there's two tasks.

One of my attempts to get the answers was to add the line commented out, `--where (p.PostTypeId = 1 or p.PostTypeId = 2)` but this does not work, giving `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'`.  This looks like pretty innocent `sql` so I'm not sure what the problem is.  With this line commented out, the code returns just the original question (which I guess means `PostTypeID` defaults to 1).

How should I include the answers and order things so that the answers are with the corresponding question?

```
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_posts 
               select @url
               , q.id
               , q.title
               , p.id
               , p.creationdate
               , p.score
               , p.body
               from posts p
               --where (p.PostTypeId = 1 or p.PostTypeId = 2)
               inner join votes v on v.PostId = p.id 
                 and v.VoteTypeId = 5
               --inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
               inner join posts q on q.id = p.id  -- same as above apparently
               inner join users u on u.accountid = '+ cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + '
                 and v.UserId = u.id;'
      exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` clauses need to go at the end, after all `JOIN`s. That's why it's giving a syntax error. But I don't think you need it; you can only favorite questions anyway. I think

```
--inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
```

shouldn't be commented out; for answers, `parentid` is the post ID of the question, and for questions it's `NULL` (hence the `COALESCE`). If you limit yourself to `q.id = p.id`, you'll only get questions precisely because of the join on the `Votes` table.

```
           insert into #all_posts 
           select @url
           , q.id
           , q.title
           , p.id
           , p.creationdate
           , p.score
           , p.body
           from posts p
           inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
           inner join votes v on v.postid = q.id
                             and v.votetypeid = 5
           inner join users u on v.userid = u.id
             and u.accountid = ' + cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + '
           order by q.id, p.creationdate;
```

The last line ensures the posts are grouped by question.

Comment: The script retrieves all the questions I have favorited (I don't think I have favorited my own much or at all).  I had tried some variations in which the `WHERE` came last but I had different errors there.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I misinterpreted your request, I'll try to fix it

Comment: Could you look at my modifications?  With your suggestion I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near ','), '. Must declare the scalar variable "@db_r_site". Must declare...` errors, I think I missed some character somewhere.

Comment: Ah, found it, closing tick was missing.  Testing now.  Looks like it works.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Looks like the answers are not with the questions but I will investigate further.

Comment: Several variations on `order by` seem not to work quite right.  Could the section `process results` be overriding the sort?

Comment: That's worth investigating, even though it is a straight `select`.

Comment: @BryanHanson You have to do the order by on that final select indeed, it is of no use to do that in the data collection step, except for warming up the planet. `order by id, creationdate` might work. Without an order by clause Sql Server will spool rows in any order, preferable from the memory cache first before fetching from disk. With newer sql server versions it becomes less and less predictable what the order will be for a projection without an explicit order by clause.

Comment: @rene Thanks so much for the background and suggestion, which works perfectly.